# Using Visual Studio 2010 Without Using Solutions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, intellisense, vi

I find myself working for a group with a very large c++ code base that does not use Visual Studio accept as a compiler. We are using make files. I feel totally crippled without the visual studio advanced features such as intellisense, go to definition, and refactoring. Are there any good tricks out there to get Visual Studio 2010 to have these features without the projects and solutions? Or, baring that are there any good VI oriented alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just use Visual Studio in tandem?  Create your own projects and solutions that duplicate the functionality of the Makefiles?  Or, if you have any influence with the group, see if you can get them to use CMake.  That way everybody can develop in their own preferred environment, and CMake will take care of generating the appropriate build files.

Comment: The features you want are based on project specific databases built by the Visual Studio tools. It won't work without the collected data.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is possible.

However, I really enjoyed using code::block (http://www.codeblocks.org/) for c++/c developpement. There is autocomplete and other feature similar to VisualStudio.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as how files don't have to be in the same directory as the solution, what you can do is create the solution in a totally different folder and include the files you want from their location. This will separate your C++ code from your solution.

Comment: Since I don't need to build from VS do you think it would be possible to build a giant stupid project with all the files int it. stash the solution/project in a directory that isn't in source control and use VS as an editor only.

Comment: @Mumakin Yes, that is what I meant in my answer. Create the soultion in a different file outside your source control and than **include** your `cpp` and `h` files. At that point you don't have to use the build from VS, but it will still be there and it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can remove the concept of a solution, but you can create a makefile project, which allows you to specifiy command lines for building/cleaning your project.

In my job all of our code builds in linux (drivers) but I do all of my coding in VS2010 using SAMBA to access the files and pterm (part of putty) to send build commands.

Comment: the main downsid eis that you will have to spend some time setting up the includes in your VS project to match what is used in the makefile, but these don't gnerally change much in a mature project.